# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale in R

Tags: r

```
MinTemp   MaxTemp  Date
8         24.3     2020-01-01
14        26.9     2020-01-02
13.7      23.4     2020-02-20
13.3      15.5     2020-12-31
```

New to R language. Above is a small part of the dataset,weather2. I want to use this dataset to find the probability of snowing using geom_point

```
Asnow=weather2 %>%
        ggplot(weather2, mapping =aes(format(Date,"%d"),(MinTemp+MaxTemp)/2))+
                       geom_point(aes(group=format(Date,"%m"),color=format(Date,"%m")),size=1)

Asnow=Asnow+
        xlab("Days per Month")+
        ylab("Temperature in US during the year")

Asnow=Asnow+scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,32,4))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,20))
Asnow=Asnow+facet_wrap(~format(Date,"%m"))
Asnow=Asnow+annotate("rect",xmin =0 ,xmax = 32,ymin = 0,ymax=32, alpha=.2)
Asnow=Asnow+labs(title="Probability of snowing")
Asnow
```

When I run it, it shows me "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". How should I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Tweak data with `lubridate` `ymd` function `month` and `day`
2. then ``ggplot`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(monthDate = month(ymd(Date)),
         dayDate = day(ymd(Date)))

ggplot(df1, mapping =aes(x = dayDate, y=(MinTemp+MaxTemp)/2, group=monthDate, color=monthDate))+
  geom_point(size=1) +
  xlab("Days per Month")+
  ylab("Temperature in US during the year") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,32,4))+scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100,20)) +
  facet_wrap(~monthDate) +
  annotate("rect",xmin =0 ,xmax = 32,ymin = 0,ymax=32, alpha=.2)+ 
  labs(title="Probability of snowing")
```

[image]

data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
         ~MinTemp, ~MaxTemp, ~Date,
  8 ,        24.3,    "2020-01-01",
  14,       26.9,     "2020-01-02",
  13.7,      23.4,     "2020-02-20",
  13.3,      15.5,     "2020-12-31"
  )

df
```

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate for your help! It able to work now!